# C volatile, and issues with hardware caching

Tags: c, multithreading, caching

I've read similar answers on this site, and elsewhere, but am still confused in a few circumstances.

I'm aware of what the standard actually guarantees us,  I understand the intended use of the keyword, and I'm well aware of the difference between the compiler caching and L1/L2/ect. caching; it's more for curiosity's sake that I understand the other cases.

Say I have a variable declared `volatile` in C. Four scenarios:

1. **Signal handlers, single threaded (As intended):** This is the problem the keyword was meant to solve. My process gets a signal callback from the OS, and I modify some `volatile` variable out of the normal execution of my process. Since it was declared `volatile`, the normal process won't store this value in a CPU register, and will always do a load from memory. Even if the signal handler writes to the `volatile` variable, since the signal handler shares the same address space as the normal process, even if the `volatile` variable was previously cached *in hardware* (i.e. L1, L2), we guarantee the main process will load the correct, updated variable. Perfect, everyone is happy.
2. **DMA-transfers, single-threaded:** Say the `volatile` variable is mapped to a region of memory for which a DMA-write is taking place. As before, the compiler won't keep the `volatile` variable in a CPU register, and will always do a load from memory; however, if that variable exists in *hardware* cache, then the load request will never reach main memory. If the DMA controller updates MM behind our backs, we'll never get the up-to-date value. In a preemptive OS, we are saved by the fact that eventually, we'll probably be context-switched out, and the next time our process resumes, the cache will be cold and we'll actually have to reload from main memory - so we'll get the correct functionality.. eventually (our own process could potentially swap that cache line out too - but again, we might waste valuable cycles before that happens). Is there standardized HW support or OS support that notifies the hardware caches when main memory is updated via the DMA controller? Or do we have to explicitly flush the cache to guarantee we arm't reading a false value? (Is this even possible in the architectures listed?)
3. **Memory-mapped registers, single-threaded:** Same as #2, except the `volatile` variable is mapped to a memory-mapped register (or an explicit IO-port). I would imagine this is a more difficult problem then #3, since at least the DMA controller will signal the CPU when it's done transferring, which gives the OS or HW a chance to do something.
4. **Mutilthreaded:** If I have a `volatile` variable, is there any guarantee of cache-coherency between multiple threads running on separate physical cores? Like sure, again, the compiler is still issuing load instructions from memory, but if the value is cached in one core's cache, is there any guarantee the same value must exist in the other core's caches? (I would imagine it's not an issue at all for hyperthreading threads on different logical cores on the same physical core, since they share physical cache memory). My overwhelming intuition says no, but thought I'd list the case here anyways.

If possible, differentiate between x64 and ARMv6/7/8 architectures, and kernel vs user land solutions.

Comment: c/c++ `volatile` has nothing to do with hardware. It just marks variable for compiler. Compiler doesn't reorder access to marked variables and doesn't optimize access to them.

Comment: @MichaelNastenko I thought made it clear I know that. Maybe I should have been clear that I was looking if there was OS/architecture support available that *could* be leveraged by the compiler outside the scope of the C standard

Comment: `volatile` means "no reorder, no optimization". Not more, not less. #1-#3 scenarios you mentioned solved by hardware. #4 usually solved by MESI or any other cache coherency protocol and c/c++ `volatile` is useless in this case.

Answer (score 1):

For 2 and 3, no there's no standardized way this would work.

Normally when doing DMA transfers one would flush the cache in a platform depending manner. Normally there's quite straight forward instructions for doing that (since now-days the caches are integrated in the CPU).

When accessing memory-mapped registers on the other hand, often the behavior is dependent on the order of writes. For example, suppose you have a UART port and write characters to it — you'll need to make sure that there is an actual write to the port each time you write to it from C.

While it might work with flushing the cache between each write, it's not what one normally does. The normal way (for ARM at least) is to set up the MMU so that writes to certain regions of address space happen uncached and in correct sequence.

This approach can also be used for memory used for DMA transfers; one could for example set up dedicated regions for use as DMA buffers and set up the MMU so that reads and writes to that region happen uncached.

On the other hand the language guarantees that all memory (well what you get from declaring variables or allocating memory using `new`) will behave in certain ways. It should be no difference between if it's multi-threaded or there's signals involved. Note that the C90 and C99 standards don't mention threads (C11 does), but they are supposed to work this way. The implementation has to make sure that the CPU's and cache are used in a way that is consistent with this (as a consequence, the OS might not be able to schedule different threads on different cores if this can't be accomplished). Consequently you should not need to flush caches in order to share data between threads, but you do need to synchronize threads and of course use `volatile` qualified data. The same is true for signal handlers even if the implementation happens to schedule them on a different core.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - notably about cache flushes and MMU-mapped non-cashable DMA regions. Just to be clear about the last paragraph though, I don't believe any C standard guarantees global visibility from writes to `volatile` memory. I think we just luck-out with that on x86 due to the way it synchronizes it's caches.

Comment: c/c++ 11 added atomic operations library for cross-platform multi-threading.

Comment: @jammie Yes, the C standard doesn't seem to cover threads. However it ought to be possible to assume that any implementation of threads behaves this way (one could argue that lies within the concept of threads). If the platform has separate cores with separate caches one should take that into consideration when designing threading functionality - otherwise it could become quite unusable.

Comment: C11 has `<threads.h>` which defines standard C threading.  Not all implementation of C11 have support for `<threads.h>` and it is not a mandatory header (so thread support is not mandatory in C11 — but the compiler should say so by defining `__STDC_NO_THREADS__`, but GCC 5.1.0 for one did not define that even when not supporting `<threads.h>` on Mac OS X).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler not everyone links with the c runtime

Comment: @JonathanLeffler For some odd reason I was reading the C99 standard. However I still think that any threading implementation worth the name should after synchronization (of the threads) has taken place have global visibility of volatile variables.

Comment: I'm not qualified to discuss the finer points of synchronization of volatile variables under threads. All I was drawing attention to is your comment "(note that the C standard doesn't mention threads, …", which I edited to "Note that the C90 and C99 standards don't mention threads (C11 does), …".  I also noted that not every C compiler that has support for C11 in general has support for C11 threads (supporting threads is optional), and gave a specific example that does not support them (but — erroneously? — does not state that it has no support for them). If you need to edit more, be my guest.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I agree, if you hadn't changed that I would have done that myself.